# reflective subcategory

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, hom-functor

Suppose that we have the following adjoint situation:
$$\hom(G-,-)\cong\hom(-,F-),$$ 
where $F:\cal K\to L$ and $G:\cal L\to K$ are functors.

So if $F$ is a right adjoint then
it has a left adjoint $G$. Suppose that the inclusion $F: \cal A\hookrightarrow K$ is right adjoint with reflections maps $r_K:K\to A$ for each $K$ in $\cal K$, so it has left adjoint $G$.

Now, how is $G$ concretely defined for this inclusion $F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's defined by the reflection property of the arrows $r_K$:

For $K\in Ob\mathcal K$, define $G(K):=\mathrm{cod}\, r_K$, 
And, for an arrow $f:K\to K'$, there is a unique $\alpha\in\mathcal A$ such that $\alpha\circ r_K=r_{K'}\circ f$. 
Define $G(f)=\alpha$, and verify that $G$ is indeed a functor, left adjoint to the inclusion.